# Set marker to place id in Android-iOS Google Maps SDK

Tags: java, swift, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I use google maps in my apps for Android-iOS-WebJS.

In web version I can load the map inside an iframe using only the place id:

```
  <iframe
  width="100%"
  height="199px"
  style={{border:'0px'}}
  loading="lazy"
  frameborder="0"
  allowFullScreen=""
  src={'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:$placeid&key=$key&maptype=roadmap&zoom=16'}>
</iframe>
```

How can i use the place id instead of lat/lng in Android/iOS Google Maps SDK? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, its possible but you may need to use additional services. For example, you may need to use Places Details services available in Places SDK for Android, as this will provide you the exact coordinates (that you can use for the marker) for the specified place_id. To get you started, you can check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/place-details

Comment: @jabamataro I want to use only the place id, not lat/lng

Comment: Its not possible, you cannot center a map in Maps SDK for Android/iOS using only a `place_id`. You need to use additional services such as Places Details to get the coordinates of that `place_id`